# Crosswalk build one APK file only

Tags: android, terminal, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I am build html5 android app using crosswalk. When i do build android it outputs two separate APK files, one for armv7 and one for x86. i just want one form armv7 only but always result bot architectures even if i put target param in command. i did these commands but still make 2 files:

- crosswalk-pkg t="arm" path
- crosswalk-pkg t=arm path
- crosswalk-pkg t="a" path
- crosswalk-pkg target="arm" path

what is actually right command to build armv7 only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to precede options with minus signs.
One if you use the shortcut (`-t`) or two if you use the entire name (`--targets`).

```
crosswalk-pkg -t="armeabi-v7a" path #builds only v7a
crosswalk-pkg -t="arm" path #builds both arm v7a & v8a
crosswalk-pkg --targets="32" ./ #<default> builds both arm & x86 for 32bits
```